# pypy translation failure on centos

Tags: linux, centos6, pypy, rpython

Not sure whether this is right forum but I am not finding good help elsewhere.

I am unable to translate PyPy 5.7.1 on a CentOS 6.7 system. I get following error.

```
[c:writing] rpython_translator_c.c
[translation:info] written: /tmp/usession-release-pypy2.7-v5.7.1-13/testing_1/testing_1.c
[6b0b3] translation-task}
[translation:info] Compiling c source...
[6b0b3] {translation-task
starting compile_c
[platform:execute] make -j 3 in /tmp/usession-release-pypy2.7-v5.7.1-13/testing_1
[platform:Error] implement_3.c: In function ‘pypy_g_ccall_ERR_reason_error_string__Unsigned’:
[platform:Error] implement_3.c:16826:11: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type
[platform:Error]   l_res_54 = ERR_reason_error_string(l_a0_47);
```

More details can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues/2553/unable-to-translate-pypy-571-on-centos-67).

Could you please provide me with some guidance? Any help is appreciated.